# Get the seasons within a range of dates

Tags: c#, algorithm, date

I need to input 2 dates representing a rang of dates. For these given dates I will need to return a list of seasons that are between those dates. Is it possible to have a solution without the need to iterate for all the days between that range?

For example for the dates: 25/12/2014 - 17/7/2015 
The result would be: Winter, Spring, Summer

---

The seasons will be already specified in a constant values 
Seasons:

- Winter: 21st December - 20th March
- Spring:  21st March -  20th June
- Summer: 21st June - 20th September
- Autumn: 21st September - 21st
  December

For example constants will be stored as below. The main problem that i'm finding is with the winter season, since the year will be increased by one and the month will start from 1.

```
    DateTimeOffset winterStart= new DateTimeOffset(year, 12, 21,0,0,0,new TimeSpan(0));
    DateTimeOffset winterEnd = new DateTimeOffset(year, 03, 19, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));

    DateTimeOffset springStart = new DateTimeOffset(year, 03, 20,0,0,0,new TimeSpan(0));
    DateTimeOffset springEnd = new DateTimeOffset(year, 06, 19, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));

    DateTimeOffset summerStart = new DateTimeOffset(year, 06, 20, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));
    DateTimeOffset summerEnd = new DateTimeOffset(year, 09, 21, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));

    DateTimeOffset autumStart = new DateTimeOffset(year, 09, 22, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));
    DateTimeOffset autumEnd = new DateTimeOffset(year, 12, 20, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));
```

Comment: What is the date-specific definition of winter, spring, summer, autumn?

Comment: Assuming you *know* the beginning and end of each season, you could simply check if the start and end of season X is within that range.

Comment: I don't know who re-opened this question but this and [closed as duplicate by me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1579587/447156) _actually_ digging the same question which is getting seasons based on a `DateTime`. Other things (calculating date difference, checking which season belongs on these difference etc..) are a little bit details. Of course these are is just my opinion which they are usually wrong.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Updated and included my season start and end dates

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes I saw that post and you are right they are similar, bit if I use that logic i would need to generated a list of dates within my ranges and check with each, which would be costly.

Comment: For what it's worth you could iterate only over months (keeping the day fixed) thus your algorithm takes at most 12 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the specific date ranges given for the seasons, you don't need to check every day in the range; I think once every 3 months should do it, e.g.

```
// get start and end as DateTime

int year;
DateTime springStart, summerStart, autumnStart, winterStart;

for (DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddMonths(3))
{ 
    year = date.Year;
    springStart = new DateTime(year, 3, 21);
    //etc...
    if (date >= springStart && date < summerStart)
    { //etc...}
    else if (date >= winterStart || date < springStart)
    { //etc...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was the simplest solution that solved my problem perfectly> I was over thinking the problem and didn't realism a simple or notation would solve my problem for winter to spring.

Answer (score 1):

Seasons are a relative term which depend upon the location. Like in Australia, its end of summer while here in Asia it is start of the summer. Also, duration of season varies across globe. In Europe, spring lasts longer while in South Asia it is merely by name. So it is very broad thing to ask for.

Comment: Even I have seen the answer of duplicate question and it is not complete in terms of variation of duration of a season